# Clarification about permission in the manifest

Tags: android

If I write this in the `manifest` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**EDIT :**

There are also these lines :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Will my application still run even if the `device` does not have a `camera` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your app will run.

You can restrict this by `android:required="true"` in `uses-feature` tag. [More](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) about `uses-feature`

***Update for edited question***:

The default value for `android:required` if not declared is `true`. So you have to add `android:required="false"` as shown bellow:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: What is really the fact of restriction ?

Comment: For example, `camera feature` is must for your app, then you can add it as `required`.

Comment: So if I add the feature , will the run crash if the device does not have a camera ?

Comment: No. The app will not be shown to users whose phone does not have camera.

Comment: Are you asking about `camera intent`? The app is not shown, so it will not be installed on phones without camera. I did not try for the case of `camera intent` if camera is not present.

Comment: yes I want to launch the camera intent , and I want the app installable even if camera is not present !

Comment: Make `android:required="false"` in `uses-feature` tag. Check the link I added with the answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your application run successfully.

`Permission` is only related to access the `Component` or `Features` of the device. like Camera, NFC, Bluetooth, etc.

e.g if i want to access camera from my app then need to add permission in `manifest.xml`  to my app for accessing camera from our app.

Comment: can you explain what NFC is please ?

Comment: @pheromix NFC is whole different topic, raise another question for it and make it more specific to programming and algorithm related

Comment: @pheromix `NFC` means `Near Field Communication` and for info go to [NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)

Comment: @AnkitBansal I am explaining about the permission. It's just an example.

Comment: @MD sorry forgot to add the tag... check the comment now

Answer (score 1):

it could run in your development environment, but it will be probably filtered out by the market. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

> Strictly, Google Play does not filter based on 
>   elements. However, it does read the elements to determine whether the
>   application has hardware feature requirements that may not have been
>   properly declared in  elements. For example, if an
>   application requests the CAMERA permission but does not declare a
>    element for android.hardware.camera, Google Play
>   considers that the application requires a camera and should not be
>   shown to users whose devices do not offer a camera.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by MD permissions are only to get access to that technology.. where uses-feature are used to restrict apps getting installed on devices that can't supply some features, as pointed by Paritosh.